# Reset switch in streamlit (antd component) when an input data is modified

Tags: python, antd, streamlit

I have a query in Streamlit.
I have some data in BigQuery which has labels, timestamp and a few values. I want to load the data for a particular label from BigQuery for a specific time duration. The duration is set using a date-range picker from streamlit extras and label is selected using a multi-select. But the page reloads for every modification in the input data. So, I want to add a switch (streamlit antd component) to load the data only when in both fields are entered and the switch should reset automatically if an input value needs modiffcation

I tried session state, but unable to influence the switch value dynamically.
Can anyone please help me out with a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.